# Excel: Product Ifs?

Tags: excel

I have time series returns, and I want to get the product based on date range.
`=product(if($B:$B,A:A,">="&$A$2,A:A,"<="&A13))` would not work because there are too many arguments for this function. Here is an example,

```
12/31/2014    100.30%
01/31/2015    100.72%
02/28/2015    102.00%
03/31/2015    101.04%
04/30/2015    99.79%
05/31/2015    101.04%
06/30/2015    99.46%
07/31/2015    100.71%
08/31/2015    97.05%
09/30/2015    96.21%
10/31/2015    101.88%
11/30/2015    100.21%
12/31/2015    99.68%
01/31/2016    98.06%
02/29/2016    97.74%
03/31/2016    100.83%
```

I want to get the product of the returns from 2015. In this case, it is 99.62%.  Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For non sorted dates, try this Array formula:

```
=PRODUCT(IF(($A$1:$A$16>=D3)*(A1:A16<=E3),B1:B16))
```

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  IF done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

As the calculations are exponential in array formulas, avoid using full column references.

[image]

---

If the dates are sorted a non array formula can be used:

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D3,A:A)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E3,A:A)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help!